# "Verify" or "verify if"?

Tags: word-usage

I often find the following phrase (as a task title, for example): "verify if the new version of the library solves the following issues list". Isn't the "if" redundant in that context (so the phrase should be "verify the new version ...")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the verb [verify](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/verify), it is normally followed by a noun or a that-clause. A that-clause would normally contain a verb, like **solve** in the following example.

> We need to verify the new version. - *noun*
>   We need to verify that the new version of the library **solves** the following issues list. - *that-clause*

Some people do use **if** rather than **that** in spoken English: in my opinion, this is not correct. In written English, usage of **if** is rare, as shown by this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verify%20that%2C%20verify%20if&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverify%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverify%20if%3B%2Cc0). **whether** is also sometimes used.

You are right that the **if** is incorrect, but the example that you quoted does contain a verb, so a **that** is required.

Comment: Maybe you can use "whether" in the following context: "I want to verify whether it is this or that"?